# When publishing InfoPath form I get error: Data connections contain parameterized queries

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, infopath, infopath-data-connections

I have Infopath form it was working correctly, I modified my form and want to publish it, it gives error bellow:

```
Data connections contain parameterized queries
```

and when I publish to my SharePoint form library it opens in InfoPath not in browser.
how to solve this issue and fix warning of data connection contains parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0):

InfoPath associates its data connections to SharePoint Lists by GUID. If this GUID were to change, it would give you the above message.

The warnings in the Design Checker are unrelated; they are just letting you know that whenever data in those fields changes, that data is sent back to the server to process.

As for why you are receiving this error, I am not 100% certain. Have you experienced this behavior again since it first occurred? If you are continuing to run into this problem, I would suggest opening a paid support ticket with Microsoft, so a Support Engineer can investigate with you further than I would be able to through these forums.